# Add/remove phone number to reject list

Tags: android, phone-call

I want to know how to add or remove a phone number to auto reject list programmatically in android?

I already detect the call and rejected with ITelephony, but i want to access to the reject list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i search you can't access to the reject list is not available